# How to get value from numbers in front of string?

Tags: vb.net

For example, 150safdsdfsdf123456 should yield 150

If the text is 150, then it's easy. Just use val. However, I want to be able to read 150sdfsdfsdafsadfwhatever too.

How can I do it?

Comment: can your string contain multiple numeric values in it? For example 150fjadfadf24ffaf1234

Comment: If so I just want the first one.

Comment: @JimThio I updated your example to reflect your last comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex (Regular Expressions) to extract the number from the String

```
Dim value1 as String
Dim temp As Regex = New Regex("\d+")
Dim match As Match = temp.Match("23333 dsadsa fd")
If match.Success Then
    value1 = match.Value
    Console.WriteLine(value1)
End If
```

Comment: OP wanted the digits at the start of the string, so `^[0-9]+` would be the regex to use. Or `New Regex("^\d+", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)` because from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#DigitCharacter): "\d matches any decimal digit. It is equivalent to the \p{Nd} regular expression pattern, which includes the standard decimal digits 0-9 as well as the decimal digits of a number of other character sets. If ECMAScript-compliant behavior is specified, \d is equivalent to [0-9]."

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim input As String = "150safdsdfsdf" ' input string contains alphanumeric characters.
Dim output As String = New String((From c As Char In input Select c Where Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray())
' output is a string variable, in the RHS select each character from the input string ('c') 
'and check whether it is a digit or not using IsDigit Function. 
' if yes it is append with the output string 
' else it is neglected.
'hence we will get only numbers as oru output 
msgbox (output)' output will be 150
```

Comment: Missing some logic. This will select only the chars. You want `Where Not Char.IsLetter(c)`

Comment: @Dan Verdolino : yes i got my mistake thank you and i made correction in my answer

Comment: Your `IsDigit(c)`, superior to my `Not Char.IsLetter(c)` as it would have contained other symbols. Thanks.

Comment: You should not just post code but also explain what it is doing and how it solves the OP's problem.

Comment: @Takendarkk : i always try to add comments along with code

Comment: Your comments say absolutely nothing about how your code is working.

Comment: @ Takendarkk : see updates in the answer hope that the comments are enough as explanation.

Comment: *From c As Char In input Select c Where Char.IsDigit(c)* as a description seems quite sufficient itself.

Comment: added comments as per the request. hope that the answer is helpfull

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the numbers at the *beginning* and nothing in the middle or end, use this

```
Dim input As String = "150safdsdfsdf150"
Dim output As String = New String(input.TakeWhile(Function(c) IsDigit(c)).ToArray())
```

What's wrong with `Val()` actually?

```
Dim s = "150.9sdfsdfsdafsadfwhatever654"
Dim d = Val(s)
```

d will be 150.9 (it accepts decimals!)

Comment: @JasonBayldon totally. It reminds me of my VB6 days. But Val seems to work well depending on what OP wants to do exactly. The question had some ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

To match a number in the beginning of the string, you can use regular expressions:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Dim input As String = "150safdsdfsdf123456"
Dim re As New Regex("^\d+")
Dim output As String = re.Match(input).Value
```

Notice a `^` symbol, it means beginning of the string. So this, for example, `a150safdsdfsdf123456` will not be matched.